# aws Private IPv4 DNS records not resolvable after changing dhcp scope

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, windows-dns

I created a dchp scope for my VPC to point to my own windows dns servers

This works as expected, linux and windows instances are automatically configured to use the IPs of my windows dns servers

BUT now records like this are not resolvable:

```
sh-4.2$ ping  ip-10-211-1-11.us-west-2.compute.internal
ping: ip-10-211-1-11.us-west-2.compute.internal: Name or service not known
```

Can I support both? Would I have to configure a conditional forwarder or something on my windows DNS servers so my instances can resolve the internal dns names aws creates for instances?

Comment: How did you resolve this @red888?